# Why are R1 and C4 connected in parallel to output in the following dimmer circuit?

Tags: diodes, triac, diac

I'm trying to understand the following dimmer circuit I found from this website: https://electronoobs.com/eng_circuitos_tut80.php:

[image]

Why are R1 and C4 connected parallel to the Triac? I have read some materials saying such design is being used to smooth the peaks. But won't that shorted the Triac part and always output full AC wave?

Comment: hint: 100nF is not a "short" at 50~60Hz

Comment: Thank you so much! @WesleyLee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R1 & C4 act as a snubber. They help to reduce voltage spikes due to the sudden change in current caused by the triac when it is switched on or off in conjunction with the inductance of the wiring.